# Variable override in bash from command line

Tags: bash, terminal, getopts

I've the following bash script. It calculates ax^2 + bx + c. Asks for a,b and c as you can see and gets x as a command line argument.

```
echo "Enter a value for a: "
read a
echo "Enter a value for b: "
read b
echo "Enter a value for c: "
read c

echo Result is `expr $a \* $1 \* $1 + $b \* $1 + $c`.

exit
```

What I want it to do now is(without any modifications to the above code) that get(override) the values of a, b & c from a file(values listed one after another, all in a line) in command line and skip asking for them in the execution of the script.

I though getopts would be the function for this purpose but I couldn't figure out how to use it. Or is it something else?

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have conflicting requirements: 1) `without any modifications to the above code` and then 2) `skip asking for them in the execution of the script`

Comment: Moreover, where "from command line" do you want to get `a, b & c` from if you don't want to ask the user for input? do you want to parse it from a file?

Comment: yeah, I want parsing from a file. I was just adding that necessity as an edit. Also I don't want any changes to the code since this assignment of mine requires it like that.

Comment: sure, can you show us what the exact format of your input file would look like?

Comment: Do you mean something with redirection?  `script < fileContainingABC`

Comment: As a note, rather than `echo "Enter a value for a: ";
read a`, I would suggest `read -p "Enter a value for a: " a`.

Comment: My input file is just 2, 3, 4; all in a new line. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the file you wanted:

```
1
2
3
```

Calling it `params.txt`, then you do:

```
$ ./myScript 2 < params 
Enter a value for a: 
Enter a value for b: 
Enter a value for c: 
Result is 11.
```

And just works.

Comment: @CanSürmeli I really doubt I'd call this "variable overriding", but I couldn't get the way I'd call it either.

Comment: You're right actually. What was wanted from me was basically just redirection but I thought hard on it as something else.